# Bash string manipulation without a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Bash, it is possible to do string manipulation on a variable, for example to get the current runlevel on a Linux machine:

```
current_runlevel=$(runlevel) #sample output: 'N 2'
current_runlevel=${current_runlevel#* }
echo $current_runlevel #sample output: '2'
```

However, is it possible to combine the two lines, so no intermediate variable is required? Using the same example, I want it to look something like:

```
current_runlevel=${$(runlevel)#* }
```

This does not work, giving the error

```
${$(runlevel)#* }: bad substitution
```

Any ideas on how it might be possible to use a literal string in Bash string manipulation expressions?

Comment: @Bill Please don't use "pls." And I don't see how that question is relevant anyway.

Comment: FWIW, you can do it in zsh, `echo ${$(echo foo)#f} -> 
oo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not really. You can, though use sed, or something similar, like:

```
current_runlevel=$( runlevel | cut -d' ' -f2 )
```

Using intermediary variable will be a bit faster though.

Comment: I would much prefer using an intermediate variable than creating a new process. It is neater, though.